# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 while getting all directories

Tags: php, while-loop, directory, notice, array-filter

So as I was working for a dropdown menu to select with style people want to choose, I got this error:

> **Notice:** Undefined offset: 1 in ...

The code:

```
<?php
$dirs=array_filter(glob('../styles/*'), 'is_dir');
$count=count($dirs);
$i = $count;
while($i>0){
    echo substr($dirs[$i], 10);
    $i=$i-1;
}
?>
```

I hope someone knows how to fix the error,
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the [`is_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) function removes items from the array which are not directories.
But the **keys will be untouched**.

You can use the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag instead of [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php
  $dirs   = glob( '../styles/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR );
  $count  = count( $dirs );
  $i      = ( $count - 1 ); // note: you must substract 1 from the total

  while( $i >= 0 ) {
    echo substr( $dirs[$i], 10 ); // i assumes that you want the first 10 chars, if yes use substr( $dirs[$i], 0, 10 )
    $i--;
  }

  /** With FOREACH LOOP **/
  $dirs = glob( '../styles/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR );
  $dirs = array_reverse( $dirs );

  foreach( $dirs as $dir ) {
    echo substr( $dir, 10 );
  }
?>
```